# Id in database using qt

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

I am new to qt. I have created a table in sql, and what I'm trying to do is to give an id whenever user adds data. For the first thing inserted it will be 1, second 2 and so on. So how to check what number was the last one? Should I create `query.prepare(sql statement)` or is there other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `QSqlQuery::lastInsertId()`.  To quote [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId):

> Returns the object ID of the most recent inserted row if the database
>   supports it. An invalid QVariant will be returned if the query did not
>   insert any value or if the database does not report the id back. If
>   more than one row was touched by the insert, the behavior is
>   undefined.

I can confirm from experience that this functionality is indeed supported for SQLite databases in Qt.

You can convert the variant to a database ID like so:

```
qint64 insertID = query.lastInsertId().toLongLong();
```